# Adding Where condition on Timestamp yields odd aggregated results

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I'm looking into Azure Monitor queries for the first time, and can't understand why adding this line:

`| where timestamp  <= ago(1days)`

makes the query results "de-aggregated."

Screenshots of the 2 separate queries/results:

### Desired Output

[image: Desired output]

### Undesired Output

[image: Undesired output]

Comment: Seams that there is no error in your query with where. can you please check if the output(you mean undesired output) is correctly group by type / problemId / innermostMessage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator you should be using is timestamp >= ago(1d), which should pick the rows which have timestamp for last 24Hrs.

Below is the sample

```
requests
| where timestamp >= ago(1d)
| summarize C = count() by itemType
```

Output from Explorer with timestamp with in the query

[image: Output from Explorer with timestamp with in the query]

```
requests
| summarize C = count() by itemType
```

Output from Explorer with timestamp from Time Range

[image: Output from Explorer with timestamp from Time Range]

[Documentation reference for using ago()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/agofunction)

Hope this helps !